# Bootstrap Grid does not fit divs in one line

Tags: html, sass, bootstrap-4

I can't understand why [this](https://codepen.io/2dev/pen/MWWbXKQ) doesn't work. There are 12 columns but it's work only with 11

---

**HTML**

```html
<section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="advantages col-12">
                <div class="col-4">one</div>
                <div class="col-4">two</div>
                <div class="col-4">three</div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**SASS**

```
.advantages
    text-align: center
    div
        display: inline-block
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove col-12 and let your col-4 sit within .row. A col must be immediately preceeded by a row.

Since 4+4+4 = 12, you don't have to define your previous col-12, and you shouldn't have to set anything to inline-block.

Answer (score 1):

It's what @Jay Kariesch said, but you can also keep `advantages` in the same div as row, like this:

```
<div class="advantages row">
```

This way you will keep `advantages` class working for all the divs inside.